# ClientContext in provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, publishing, iis7

I have developed the Provider hosted app. Using two way.

1. I have create Self Signed certificate and created app using that.
   When I run the app from Visual Studio it runs perfectly. After that
   I publish my app's Web Application to my local IIS. And it works
   from there also when I hit F5 from Visual Studio.

   But, When I add my .app file to AppCatalog of my site. And install
   my app to site and try to run that app, at that time it gives me
   error    `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
   error: (401) Unauthorized`
2. I have also create app without using self signed certificate and
   created the ClientID and ClientSecret from my site and created app
   using that. And then I publish my app's Web Application to IIS and
   try to run that app It gives me error of   `The parameter 'token'
   cannot be a null or empty string`

Is there any other way to create Client Context object for my App?
How to solve this Issues..?

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a bit of setup required to deploy a provider-hosted App in a local (on-premises) SharePoint farm. Eric Shupps has a blog post that details everything you need to do to get this working.

[Configuring High Trust Apps for SharePoint 2013](https://www.ericshupps.com/configuring-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Hi Rob Windsor, the above provided link was broken. Could you please update the link..

Comment: The link has been updated